Is there a way to `exec` a pipeline or exit shell after launching a pipeline?
I'm writing a shell wrapper script that is supposed to act as a pager (receiving input on stdin and performing output on a tty).
This wrapper prepares environment and command lines, then launches two processes in a pipeline: first one is a non-interactive filter and the last one is the actual pager that needs to control a tty (or, rather, it spawns the actual pager itself):
#!/bin/bash

...

col -bx | bat "${bat_args[@]}" --paging=always

The resulting process tree is thus:
<parent>
\- wrapper.sh
   |- col -bx (dies)
   \- bat ...
      \- less ...

The col -bx process exits after filtering the input and is reaped by the shell.

Is it possible to get rid of the shell process, such that it won't hang around for as long as the pager is running?
I thought of a workaround by using process substitution:
exec bat "${bat_args[@]}" --paging=always < <(col -bx)

However, the col -bx process is not reaped by the shell and remains in the Z state. Is there a "right" way to write this wrapper?

zombies are irrelevant.  They will go away eventually, like when the parent process exists, probably the original shell.

You can also do:
#!/bin/zsh -
col -bx | exec bat "${bat_args[@]}" --paging=always

Or:
#!/bin/ksh -
col -bx | exec bat "${bat_args[@]}" --paging=always

(not with the pdksh-derived implementations of ksh)
#!/bin/bash -

shopt -s lastpipe
col -bx | exec bat "${bat_args[@]}" --paging=always

In the end functionally equivalent to what you do with a redirection from a process substitution but skip that extra fd shuffling and named pipe creation (or /dev/fd/x opening on systems that have them (most)).
In any case, to reap a process, you need to wait for it. With ksh/zsh/bash -O lastpipe and those approaches above, col will be a child of the process that eventually executes bat, so bat will get a SIGCHLD when col dies, what it does with it is up to it. If it doesn't handle that SIGCHLD (few applications do for processes they've not spawned themselves), col will show as a zombie until bat terminates, after which the col process will be re-parented to the child sub-reaper or init and taken care of there.
In any case, note that in A | B, ksh doesn't wait for A either unless you set the pipefail option.
Now, per POSIX under XSI option, and that applies also on Linux,

If the parent process of the calling process has set its SA_NOCLDWAIT flag or has set the action for the SIGCHLD signal to SIG_IGN:

The process' status information (see Status Information), if any, shall be discarded.
The lifetime of the calling process shall end immediately. If SA_NOCLDWAIT is set, it is implementation-defined whether a SIGCHLD signal is sent to the parent process.
If a thread in the parent process of the calling process is blocked in wait(), waitpid(), or waitid(), and the parent process has no remaining child processes in the set of waited-for children, the wait(), waitid(), or waitpid() function shall fail and set errno to [ECHILD].

Otherwise:

Status information (see Status Information) shall be generated.
The calling process shall be transformed into a zombie process. Its status information shall be made available to the parent process until the process' lifetime ends.
[...]


(emphasis mine).
Now, not all shells will let you ignore SIGCHLD, it being so essential to its functioning (the whole point of shells is to run commands and report their exit status), but it looks like current versions of bash (5.2.21 in my test) at least do, so in:
#!/bin/bash -

shopt -s lastpipe
trap '' CHLD
col -bx | exec bat "${bat_args[@]}" --paging=always

The process running col would never become a zombie as long as bat doesn't un-ignore SIGCHLD before col exits.
In any case, zombies are not necessarily a bad thing. The zombie stage is part of the life a process, most processes go through there between the time they die and their parent (or init or child sub-reaper) acknowledge it.

Thanks! Combining lastpipe and exec-ing the last command in the pipeline is neat, I was thinking in that direction but did not think good enough. But I'd never think to try to ignore SIGCHLD — I wasn't aware that setting an empty handler translates into SIG_IGN :-)
